# Android constructor arguments error. Unable to initialise object.

Tags: android, constructor, arguments

I'm trying to use a date picker to feed user input back into some text fields. I'm using a Date picker object and listener. I'm getting a error stating 'Cannot find symbol variable MyListener.  on the line:

```
    DatePickerFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment(MyListener);
```

If I replace 'MyListner' with 'this' I get this message

> "error: constructor DatePickerFragment in class DatePickerFragment
>   cannot be applied to given types; required: NewClutch.MyListener
>   found: NewClutch reason: actual argument NewClutch cannot be converted
>   to NewClutch.MyListener by method invocation conversion"

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    private MyListener listener;
    public DatePickerFragment(MyListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }
    int selectedDate;
    View targetView;
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
        selectedDate = day+month+year;
        if(listener!=null){
            listener.theDateHasChanged(selectedDate, targetView);
        }
    }
    public int getSelectedDate() {
        return selectedDate;
    }

    public int setTargetBox(View view) {
        targetView = view;
    }
}
/* close datePickerFragment class */
public void showDatePickerDialog(View view ) {
    DatePickerFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment(this);
    datePicker.setTargetBox(view);
    datePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    //int output = ((DatePickerFragment)datePicker).getSelectedDate();

    }
public class MyListener {
    public void theDateHasChanged(int selectedDate, View targetView) {
        if(targetView.getId() == R.id.clutch_date_laid_box)
        {
            // --- find the text view --
            TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_two_box);
            // -- change text size --
            txtView.setText(selectedDate);
            return;
        }
        if(targetView.getId() == R.id.clutch_name_box)
        {
            // --- find the text view --
            TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_one_box);
            // -- change text size --
            txtView.setText(selectedDate);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't contain `new DatePickerFragment(MyListener)` - it contains `new DatePickerFragment(this)`...

Comment: I have tried both. As I explain in the text.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. Well where did you expect it to get `MyListener` from? You need to actually create an instance of `MyListener` somewhere... it's not clear that you're ever doing that.